# Easy building of Chromium base (libchrome) library

Tags: c++, build, chromium

I've been working with Chromium codebase for some time and get accustomed to its great [base library (aka libchrome)](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/packages/libchrome). The problem is that while great and versatile this library wasn't intended to be used outside of Chromium so it is really problematic to use it as a standalone library.

[Library's page](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/packages/libchrome) states that for other Google's projects they either released some inner packages or used [scons build script](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromiumos/overlays/chromiumos-overlay.git;a=blob;f=chromeos-base/libchrome/files/SConstruct-125070;h=67e62718e16134e52c929a5dcda24224740616b2;hb=HEAD) which can be used for building the library. Unfortunately neither this script nor its [more recent version](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromiumos/overlays/chromiumos-overlay.git;a=blob;f=chromeos-base/libchrome/files/SConstruct-180609;h=1e362302fb735d31684ef3ea2616ac0c7ce1cfd1;hb=refs/heads/master) allowed me to compile it. I'v got some errors either about wrong flags or missing input files. Possibly some of patches placed in the same directory as script could help but there is not description which to use and in what order.

On [some blog](http://blog.dimitridiakopoulos.com/2014/05/14/building-the-chromiumbase-library/) I found suggestion that one could fetch whole Chromium instead, together with its toolchain and configure it to build just that one library. But that would be really slow and not very portable. If I were to develop something serious one day it would force people to download a lot of unnecessary stuff.

Do any of you know some fast and reliable way to build that library? It might be more complicated as long as it could be automated by a script and don't make one setup `PATH` variables and download several GB of overhead data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mini_chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/mini_chromium/) provides a standalone build of the base lib but does not provide Windows builds. If you need those you'll have to add yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded GYP from `svn checkout http://gyp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ gyp-read-only` and then run command `../gyp-read-only/gyp --depth=. mini_chromium.gyp` from `mini_chromium` dir next to the gyp checkput. Then I was able to build Windows version in the Visual Studio.

Comment: does mini_chromium support android?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can take a look at my port: https://github.com/zhchbin/chromium-base based on mini_chromium. Besides mini_chromium, I moved most of chromium/src/base code into this standalone repository. It's now working on windows and linux.

Answer (score 2):

I want to elaborate on @krishna's answer.

### Building mini_Chromium

To install [mini_chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/mini_chromium/) you can perform following steps:

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/mini_chromium
cd mini_chromium

# On POSIX
export GYP_GENERATORS=ninja
gyp --depth=. mini_chromium.gyp
# On Windows
set GYP_GENERATORS=ninja
gyp.bat --depth=. mini_chromium.gyp

ninja -C out/Release base
ninja -C out/Debug   base
```

That requires having only GYP and ninja installed.

### Building libchrome

With some additional effort I was able to build full libchrome (on Windows), however it required a lot of hacking and is very prone to break if Chromium developers change something:

```
# First checkout and initialize shallow Chromium SVN repository
svn checkout --depth empty http://src.chromium.org/chrome/trunk/src/ libchrome
cd libchrome
svn update --set-depth empty chrome/
svn update --set-depth empty third_party/
# Now fill it with only dependencies required to build target 'base'
svn update --set-depth infinity base/
svn update --set-depth infinity build/
svn update --set-depth empty    chrome/VERSION
svn update --set-depth infinity testing/
svn update --set-depth infinity third_party/android_crazy_linker/
svn update --set-depth infinity third_party/ashmem/
svn update --set-depth infinity third_party/libevent/
svn update --set-depth infinity third_party/libxml/
svn update --set-depth infinity third_party/modp_b64/
svn update --set-depth infinity third_party/zlib/
# Now checkout dependencies from outside of main Chromium repository
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/buildtools buildtools
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/testing/gtest testing/gtest
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/deps/icu52.git third_party/icu
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/deps/psyco_win32 third_party/psycho
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp tools/gyp
```

At this point all dependencies are fetched but code still wouldn't build. We need to modify two files to make thinks work:

- `build/gyp_chromium` - around line 30 there are paths that need to be checked on scripts startup. Leave only:

  ```
  # Add paths so that pymod_do_main(...) can import files.
  sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(chrome_src, 'build', 'android', 'gyp'))
  sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(chrome_src, 'tools'))
  ```
- `build/all.gyp` - remove dependencies not related to `base`. Result should look similar to [this GIST](https://gist.github.com/MateuszKubuszok/857da854b1c63e729790).

With those preparations done, now we can build target `base` (assuming that [depot tools](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/install-depot-tools) are installed):

```
build/gyp_chromium --depth=. --root-target=base
ninja -C out/Release base
ninja -C out/Debug base
```

I have to remind though that I built that on Windows. Whole hacky workaround let me download 500MB of code instead of 2,7GB but it's not supported and it can stop working any moment. But probably when it break it should be still relatively easy to fix as it will be probably a matter of adding a dependency or two.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30913546/285594  - you seems to look like my kind of more detailed writer. can you please check why this answer failed to build, i tried all but it failed to build.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/WangTingMan/chromebase.
Clone it then you can open it with visual studio 2019 or visual studio 2022 directly and compile it directly.
No any other tools need, just only visual studio is enough.